# Why do I need to use a setter - instead of a getter - to set data?

Tags: java, getter-setter

Suppose I have a class which has as one of its fields an object, `SampleData`, and a getter and setter for the field.

```
public class someClass
{
    private SampleData sampleData;

    public SampleData getSampleData()
    {
         return sampleData;
    }

    public void setSampleData( SampleData sampleData )
    {
        this.sampleData = sampleData;
    }
}
```

Say I've instantiated `someClass`. And suppose I have another `SampleData` already available. So with the setter I would do the following,

```
someClassInstantiated.setSampleData( anotherSampleData );
```

Why do I need to use the setter, `setSampleData` to set the value of this field?
 Why can't I do something like this instead?

```
SampleData sampleData = someClassInstantiated.getSampleData();
sampleData = anotherSampleData;
```

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: Have you tried it? `SampleData sampleData = someClassInstantiated.getSampleData();` says, "point `sampleData` to the same location as the return result of `getSampleData`", then `sampleData = anotherSampleData;` says "point `sampleData` to `anotherSampleData`" - this doesn't change what `someClassInstantiated.sampleData` is pointing to  do

Comment: The whole purpose of getters and setters is so that external entities cannot modify the internal state of your objects without your object controlling how it's done.

Comment: @MadProgrammer. Yes I've tried it. I get null when I use the getter method.

Comment: @Joker Just because Java hides them, doesn't mean it doesn't make use of memory pointers - all you're doing is changing the memory location various pointers point to, not their value

Comment: @MadProgrammer. So if I point to a location that contains data, then why null? If I print both the sampleData and anotherSampleData after using the getter method, sampleData is null and anotherSampleData is not null, but from what you are saying they are pointing to the same location.

Comment: Because you've not actually changed `someClassInstantiated.sampleData` to change where it's pointing, you've only changed where `sampleData` (the other one) is pointing

Comment: @MadProgrammer. Thanks, that clears it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People seem to forget that Java still uses memory pointers to reference data, it just hides all the awesome pointer arithmetic that C/C++ has ;)

So, basically, when you do this `SampleData sampleData = someClassInstantiated.getSampleData();`, `sampleData` is pointing to the same memory location as `someClassInstantiated.sampleData`, for example...

[image: Initial State]

How ever, when you do `sampleData = anotherSampleData;`, you change the memory location that `sampleData` is pointing to be the same as `anotherSampleData`, this doesn't affect what `someClassInstantiated.sampleData` is pointing, it remains unchanged

[image: Updated State]

> So if I point to a location that contains data, then why null? If I print both the sampleData and anotherSampleData after using the getter method, sampleData is null and anotherSampleData is not null, but from what you are saying they are pointing to the same location

This is because `someClassInstantiated.sampleData` still points to `null` - this is the default value assigned to it when it was instantiated and (based on your example) has not been changed.

In the long run, you really, really don't want it to work the way you're trying to use it, as it breaks the principle of encapsulation, where the object is responsible for the management of the data.

Answer (score 1):

In java you have references. Equality operator (`=`) is used to assign a `reference variable` to refer to an `Object`.

Lets assume `someClassInstantiated.getSampleData()` returns `ObjectA`. This is same object as referred by the 
`private SampleData sampleData;`

```
SampleData sampleData = someClassInstantiated.getSampleData();
```

Currently `sampleData` refers `ObjectA`.

Also lets assume `anotherSampleData` refers to `ObjectB`.

```
sampleData = anotherSampleData;
```

Now `sampleData` refers to `ObjectB`. Now this does not have any impact upon Object referred by `private SampleData sampleData;`, it still refers to `ObjectA`.

Only if the object of `SampleData` is mutable and then using `.` dot operator, if the state is modified, same modified state would be reflected by reading object's state y either of the reference variables. Equality operator simply assigns the variable to refer to an object (or to a primitive typed value)

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
SampleData sampleData = someClassInstantiated.getSampleData();
sampleData = anotherSampleData;
```

in the first line you are making reference to field of `someClassInstantiated`, however this field does not refer to your object sampleData, hence changing it would not change the values in `someClassInstantiated`

In other words, these objects are not binded together. If you would like to change the value of the field whenever some other value changes use e.g. [observer design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).